# use of like statement with or in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on a table with name exp1, in this table there is a column named filename which contain data like exp_ara1.txt, exp_gma1.txt, exp_sly1.txt., exp_rcy1.txt, exp_thy1.txt

By using MySQL query I want to select only those rows which have filename either %ara% or %gma%.
I am using following command:

```
Select * from exp1 where filename LIKE ('%ara%' OR '%gm%');
```

but it is results
 Your SQL query has been executed successfully.
 MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is one of the best process as if you have **more multiple words** to put in like::

```
$sql = array('0'); // Stop errors when $words is empty

foreach($words as $word){
    $sql[] = 'filename LIKE %'.$word.'%'
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM exp1 WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $sql);
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it helped you and for others.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Select * from exp1 where filename LIKE ('%ara%') OR filename LIKE ('%gm%');
```

Comment: The parentheses are not needed. To make the code more readable you can put them around the subexpressions: `(filename LIKE '%ara%') OR (filename LIKE '%gm%')`

Comment: @axiac Actually I'm surprised the parentheses don't cause an error, as `LIKE` isn't a function.

Answer (score 1):

Using `REGEXP` we can write a single term to match using an alternation:

```
SELECT *
FROM exp1
WHERE filename REGEXP '(.*ara.*)|(.*gm.*)'
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you don't have the option to use the `CONTAINS` function like in SQL Server or Oracle, which is what it looks like your trying to do.

```
SELECT * 
FROM exp1
WHERE (filename LIKE ('%ara%') OR filename LIKE ('%gm%'));
```